# render ID3D11Texture2D with resizing in Directx11

Tags: directx-11

I'm trying to migrate directx-9 to directx-11.

In my application, I only need to render texture2d  (D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC/D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT) with suitable size but I cannot find any tutorial discussing on it. Did anyone know how to do it?

In other words, How do I render the ID3D11Resource* from D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile on the window?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: A good idea for migrating would be first to learn about directx11, there are numerous tutorials out there on how to properly initialize directx11, and creating shaders for it using HLSL, as well as how to bind textures for the shaders to render them to the window.  A quick google search for that will bring up a tutorial from rastertek: http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html, which is a decent series.

Comment: thank you Eddge, the tutorial helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Rather than continue to use the [deprecated D3DX11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) library, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the `SpriteBatch` class in particular. See the tutorial [Sprites and textures](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures)

See also [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)